# React Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access imported constant

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm encountering an error in my React application that throws the following message:

```
editApplication.api.ts:141 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ResourcePermissions' before initialization
    at Module.ResourcePermissions (editApplication.api.ts:141:1)
    at ./src/pages/resources/components/editApplication/EditApplication.tsx (EditApplication.tsx:35:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

Despite correctly importing ResourcePermissions, the error seems unrelated to its usage within my codebase. Here's how I defined the variable:

```js
// resources.route.tsx

export const ResourcePermissions = {
  readApp: "app:read",
  writeApp: "app:write",
};
```

I'm using ResourcePermissions outside the exported functional component within an array:

```js
// Resources.tsx

import { ResourcePermissions } from "pages/resources/resources.route";
import BasicInformation from "./components/basicInformation/BasicInformation";


const TabComponents = [
  {
    title: "basicInformation",
    key: "basic-information",
    permission: ResourcePermissions.readApp,
    component: () => {
      return (
        <BasicInformation/>
      );
    },
  }
]
```

The error references a line (editApplication.api.ts:141:1) seemingly unrelated to any usage of ResourcePermissions.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this would be immensely helpful.

Troubleshooting Performed:

Verified proper import of ResourcePermissions.
Ensured proper import orders across files to prevent circular dependencies.
Examined bundler configurations and stack traces for potential causes.

Upon further investigation, I created a separate file resource.const.ts and exported ResourcePermissions from that file. Surprisingly, importing from this file resolved the issue.

Comment: just a comment, you're not using `ResourcePermissions` in the editApplication.api.ts script at all right as you mentioned? it'd be helpful if you add the code for that file in your question which the error mentions.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't share the editApplication.api.ts code due to restrictions. I can assure you that, the `ResourcePermissions` isn't directly or indirectly referenced or utilized in the editApplication.api.ts. It's worth to mention that I can use `ResourcePermissions` inside component and there will be no error.

Comment: isolate the `ResourcePermissions` object in its own file that doesn't have any imports and see if the issue persists. If it doesn't it's a dependency order issue and you need to extract the constants in a 3rd file. Otherwise, the only other thing that comes to mind to try is making the object a return value of a function (with the function keyword) and calling the function instead of using the object.